How to understand and compare ADC errors between LTC2314-14 and internal ADC of STM32F103
We are going to sample and curve a short, fast-changing signal of around 34 us, with a reasonable resolution of at least 10 bits.

A 4 Msps ADC would provide us around ~138 data points in 34 us
The peak-to-peak signal is around 3V, (-3 V to 0 V)

Since we need the curve as good as possible and beucase of the errors on STM32FG474 ADC:

We considered using an external ADC as we thought an external chip would do better. With a quick search, we found a good match (spec-wise), the LTC2314-14. It is a 14 bits, 4.5 Msps ADC and we thought it's gonna be a better match. However, we found this specs on the datasheet:

The total unadjusted error (which I use for quick comparison) is 30 LSBs maximum, around 6 times the STM32 and the same goes with other specs (e.g. offset error)

Is the STM32G474 really a better ADC considering the values on the table? while a LTC2314-14 is priced around 20x of the STM32G474
Is the total unadjusted error a good feature of comparison between these two ADCs?


14 bits with 30 LSB is much better than 7LSB on 12 bit! Or do I miss something? Also remember that those STM32 specs are with only the ADC active. If you have other stuff running on chip performance degrades.

@Jeroen3 14bits is 4 times the resolution of the 12bits on STM32, and doing the same for the error means 4x7 = 28 LSBs which seems still better than LTC model. For a 3V reference, the 30LSB error of 14 bits is around 0.0054V and the 7LSB error of 12bits is 0.0051V. I don't know if this type of calculation is correct or not.
